# Can't pull information from the other sheet in my Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I’m working on an Excel workbook that automatically populates a PDF with the information present in an Excel sheet. When I try the the macro that creates the PDF I encounter a “Variable not defined” error with Sheet1 being highlighted. I used to have all the buttons shown in the picture on one sheet, I assume that is what is causing an error since I moved them to another sheet. Essentially I want to use the information in Sheet1 to populate the PDF documents In sheet 2. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Buttons that used to be in Sheet1

[image: Buttons that used to be in Sheet1]

Error code
[image: Error code]

```
Option Explicit
Enum W32_Window_State
    Show_Normal = 1
    Show_Minimized = 2
    Show_Maximized = 3
    Show_Min_No_Active = 7
    Show_Default = 10
End Enum
 
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Function OpenURL(URL As String, WindowState As W32_Window_State) As Boolean
 
' Opens passed URL with default application, or Error Code (<32) upon error
 
    Dim lngHWnd As Long
    Dim lngReturn As Long
 
    lngReturn = ShellExecute(lngHWnd, "open", URL, vbNullString, _
        vbNullString, WindowState)
   
    OpenURL = (lngReturn > 32)
End Function
Sub PDFTemplate()
Dim PDFFldr As FileDialog
Set PDFFldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With PDFFldr
    .Title = "Select PDF file to attach'"
    .Filters.Add "PDF Type Files", "*.pdf", 1
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection
    ActiveSheet.Range("D12").Value = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NoSelection:
End Sub
Sub SavePDFFolder()
Dim PDFFldr As FileDialog
Set PDFFldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With PDFFldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSel:
    ActiveSheet.Range("D17").Value = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NoSel:
End Sub
Sub CreatePDFForms()
Dim PDFTemplateFile, NewPDFName, SavePDFFolder, FirstName As String
Dim EplyrName As String
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long


With Sheet1
    LastRow = .Range("E9999").End(xlUp).Row  'LastRow
    PDFTemplateFile = .Range("D12").Value 'Template File Name
    SavePDFFolder = .Range("D17").Value 'Save PDF Folder
    OpenURL "" & PDFTemplateFile & "", Show_Maximized
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00006
```

Comment: Please try `Sheets("Sheet1")`. Its codename might be different. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em5JZ.png

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome Tried this but now the PDF wont open

Comment: Figured it our just had to reference both sheets I only referenced one